# Desktop scrambled after suspension

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, desktop-environments

I get my desktop scrambled after suspension. And dont know what to do to solve it. Any ideas?

I have 2 screens (extended environment) with an nvidia GeForceGT 750M (dual nvidia-intel chipset laptop) and Im using Ubuntu 18.10

Thanks in advance

Desktop and Nvidia
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FRFp.jpg

Comment: I was having some issues involving the lock screen after suspension - for me, setting the "blank screen" in Settings->Power to "Never" made the problem go away.

Comment: I solve it, it was the image selected for blocking screen  and the setting changed to "Spanned" at the appearence with tweaks